# Oracle converting ISO Date to computer locale date/time

Tags: c#, oracle

I insert into an Oracle DB Table using the following insert string (Approx -- There's 140 columns so I won't show it all):

"INSERT INTO AMS_ASSET_CS_IFACEOUT VALUES ( 'abcdef', 'abcdef', to_date('2010-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), ... )"

Then a couple of seconds later I run the following code snippet:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function: GetRecord
    /// Description: Creates a new AMS-Asset and populates the
    /// properties of this asset by evaluating properties provided
    /// by the OracleDataReader.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader"> One record of information from the open connection.</param>
    /// <returns> A fully created AMS-Asset record. </returns>
    private static AmsAsset GetRecord(OracleDataReader reader)
    {
        AmsAsset newRecord = new AmsAsset();

        for (int propertyIndex = 0; propertyIndex < reader.FieldCount; propertyIndex++)
        {
            string propertyName = reader.GetName(propertyIndex).ToLower();
            string propertyValue = reader.GetValue(propertyIndex).ToString();
            int propertyValueAsInteger = 0;

            bool isPropertyAnInteger = Int32.TryParse(propertyValue, out propertyValueAsInteger);

            if (isPropertyAnInteger)
            {
                newRecord.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(newRecord, propertyValueAsInteger, null);
            }
            else
            {
                newRecord.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(newRecord, propertyValue, null);
            }
        }

        return newRecord;
    }
```

The date value I inserted into my database is now returned as "1/31/2010 12:00:00 AM."

I'm not entirely sure why... What are my options? Do I need to just code a conversion from the format I'm being given back into ISO

Regards,

Sean Anderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you inserted into Database using an unambiguous 'YYYY-MM-DD' format date, it is correctly stored in database.

When you read it out and display that date, the format is dependent on your regional settings.

I suggest you use an explicit format specifier for displaying.

Comment: Just to confirm, would this be an acceptable means of fixing this problem? 

    [IgnoreFirst]
    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    [Serializable]
    public class AmsAsset
    {
        public string assetnum { get; set; }
        public string changeby { get; set; }
        public string changedate
        {
            get
            {
                return String.Format("{0:YYYY-MM-DD}", changedate);
            }
            set
            {
            }
        } 
        ....

EDIT: Ehh, formatting turned out terrible. I'll fix it though. THANKS!